# Does the "@" symbol have a special meaning when surrounding a CMake variable?

Tags: cmake

While looking through the [ITK](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK) source code I've come across a number of files like [this](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/v4.9.0/CMake/ExternalData_config.cmake.in), which have the suffix `.cmake.in` and which define a number of variables (strings?), where the value is identical to the variable name, but with `@` symbols prepended/appended.  For example:

```
set(ExternalData_OBJECT_STORES "@ExternalData_OBJECT_STORES@")
```

What is the purpose of these declarations?  Does the `@` symbol have a special meaning in this context?  I tried searching for this in the [CMake Language Syntax Wiki](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Language_Syntax), but there were no occurrences of `@` on the page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Files with suffix `.in` are usually intended for configuration via command [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/configure_file.html). All sequences `@NAME@` within such files are translated to value of variable `NAME`.

Outside of `configure_file` / `string(CONFIGURE)` symbol `@` has no special meaning in CMake.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev, both link and explaination were helpful!

Comment: Is it possible to escape `@`? so that `@NAME@` stays `@NAME@`?

Comment: @bambino307: It seems `configure_file` doesn't support escaping. You could define a variable - `set(AT "@")` - and use this variable in the configured file: `@AT@NAME@AT@`.